# SQL Server insert Attribute to top node of xml

Tags: sql-server, xml, insert, attributes, root

I want to insert an attribute to the root node of XML datatype.  If I know the name of the root node is Quote, then I can insert like this:

```
    DECLARE @myDoc xml;     
DECLARE @id int;
SET @id = 12345; 

SET @myDoc = '<Quote>       
    <Close>
        123
    </Close>    
</Quote>'  ;  
SET @myDoc.modify('           
insert attribute ID {sql:variable("@id") }           
into   (/Quote)[1] ');  

SELECT @myDoc;
```

What if I don't know the root node name?  I want to insert an attribute to the root node regardless of root name.  I'm using SQL Server 2008r2.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(/*)[1]` to locate root node:

```
SET @myDoc = '<Quote>       
    <Close>
        123
    </Close>    
</Quote>'  ;  
SET @myDoc.modify('           
insert attribute ID {sql:variable("@id") }           
into (/*)[1] ');
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f1a1e/5)